# Trouble connecting to MongoDB Atlas from Robo 3T

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, robo3t

I have created a free `Atlas` account and setup a cluster. I am trying to connect to the atlas cluster from the `Robo 3T` GUI. I have made the following configuration,

In the connection tab, I have specified all the cluster nodes with the type set to `Replica Set`
[image]

In the Authentication tab I have provided the credentials of the admin user.

SSH is not checked

TLS is set to use with the self signed certificate.
[image]

No changes are made in the Adbanced tab.

But when I try to connect, it is failing with the following error,

```
6:03:06 PM  Info: Settings saved to: /Users/sandeshaj/.3T/robo-3t/1.4.1/robo3t.json
6:03:06 PM  Info: Connecting to digify [Replica Set]cluster0-shard-00-02.hfjr8.mongodb.net:27017...
6:03:06 PM  Info: Settings saved to: /Users/sandeshaj/.3T/robo-3t/1.4.1/robo3t.json
6:03:24 PM  Info: Settings saved to: /Users/sandeshaj/.3T/robo-3t/1.4.1/robo3t.json
6:03:24 PM  Info: Replica set's cached set name cleared. Using user entered set name.
6:06:14 PM  Error: Establish connection failed. TLS tunnel failure: Network is unreachable or TLS connection rejected by server. Reason: Connect failed. Connection: digify
6:06:14 PM  Warning: Failed to ping the server. Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary", tags: [ {} ] } for set cluster0-shard-00-00
```

[image]

In the Atlas account, I have given access to all the IPs, [image]

What else should I do to connect to Atlas DB from the Robo3T GUI.

PS: I even tried with unchecking TLS. Also, tried by giving the set name as `cluster0-shard-0` as suggested in the setup I am doing for the app https://github.com/digifi-io/loan-origination-system

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, strange, I seem to be unable to login myself...

Comment: Have you provided these details in Authentication tab? *Database:* admin, *User Name:* Your user name, *Password:* your password, *Auth Mechanism:* SCRAM-SHA-1

Comment: Yes, I have. The credential used has admin access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the replica set name in Atlas was different than what I was feeding in `Robo 3T`. When I did `db.runCommand( { isMaster: 1 } )` on the shell, it gave the following output,

```
{
    "hosts" : [
        "cluster0-shard-00-00.hfjr8.mongodb.net:27017",
        "cluster0-shard-00-01.hfjr8.mongodb.net:27017",
        "cluster0-shard-00-02.hfjr8.mongodb.net:27017"
    ],
    "setName" : "atlas-n8lsue-shard-0",
    "setVersion" : 2,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "primary" : "cluster0-shard-00-02.hfjr8.mongodb.net:27017",
    "tags" : {
        "provider" : "AWS",
        "nodeType" : "ELECTABLE",
        "workloadType" : "OPERATIONAL",
        "region" : "US_EAST_1"
    },
    "me" : "cluster0-shard-00-02.hfjr8.mongodb.net:27017",
    "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000006"),
    "lastWrite" : {
        "opTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1603813903, 3),
            "t" : NumberLong(6)
        },
        "lastWriteDate" : ISODate("2020-10-27T15:51:43Z"),
        "majorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1603813903, 3),
            "t" : NumberLong(6)
        },
        "majorityWriteDate" : ISODate("2020-10-27T15:51:43Z")
    },
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 100000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2020-10-27T15:51:47.854Z"),
    "logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes" : 30,
    "connectionId" : 643442,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "maxWireVersion" : 8,
    "readOnly" : false,
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1603813903, 3),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"ZQK/mzsowFmDfsrDc4kfXBAXIl4="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6875773608992440322")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1603813903, 3)
}
```

So I changed the set name to `atlas-n8lsue-shard-0` from `Cluster-shard-0` and the connection is success now

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

1. Go to Atlas > Clusters
2. Click the "Connect" button
3. Connect using Mongo Compass
4. And you will see `mongodb+srv://...` connection string.
5. Copy/Past your Robo3T **From Srv**

Also you can try MongoDB Compass, it is a powerful tool more than Robo3T.

Comment: In the connection string, you will not see the replica set name